# Find files matching patterns in Perl

Tags: regex, perl

I am taking the user input via -f option, and whatever he enters, accordingly files are being searched recursively.

My problem is: When user enters "tmp*", then also it searches for "abctmp", "xyztmp" etc. What I want to do is, only files starting with tmp should come.
In short, whatever user enters accordingly files should be pushed to array.

Currently I am doing this, but I am sure there's some classy, short way to do it.

```
#! /perl/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Find;
use getopt::Long;

my $filename="tmp*.txt";
find( { wanted     => \&wanted,
        preprocess => \&dir_search,
}, '.');

sub wanted{
    my $regex;
    my $myop;
    my @mylist;
    my $firstchar= substr($filename, 0,1); # I am checking first character. 
                                           # Whether it's ".*tmp" or just "tmp*"

    if($filename=~ m/[^a-zA-Z0-9_]/g){     #If contain wildcard
        if($firstchar eq "."){             # first character "."
            my $myop  = substr($filename, 1,1);
            my $frag  = substr($filename,2);
            $filename = $frag;
            $regex    = '\b(\w' . ${myop}. ${filename}. '\w*)\b'; 
            # Has to find whatever comes before 'tmp', too
        } else {
            $regex    = '\b(' . ${myop}. ${filename}. '\w*)\b'; 
            # Like, "tmp+.txt" Only search for patterns starting with tmp
        }
        if($_ =~ /$regex/) {
            push(@mylist, $_);
        }
    } else {
    if($_ eq $filename) { #If no wildcard, match the exact name only.
        push(@mylist, $_);
    }
}

}

sub dir_search {
    my (@entries) = @_;
    if ($File::Find::dir eq './a') {
        @entries = grep { ((-d && $_ eq 'g') || 
                      ((-d && $_ eq 'h')  || 
                     (!(-d && $_ eq 'x')))) } @entries; 
    # Want from 'g' and 'h' folders only, not from 'x' folder
    }
    return @entries;
}
```

And another thing is, I want to search for only '.txt' files. Where should I put that condition?

Comment: Huh? I have no idea what you just said. Judging from the 4 downvotes and no answers after 14 hours, I'm not the only one who's confused. Please try to explain more clearly what you're trying to accomplish. "When user enters 'tmp*'" where, how, and why? "It searches for..." where, how, and why? I have the feeling that what you're trying to do is probably pretty simple, but nobody can figure out what you're trying to say.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/perl/bin/perl

sub rec_dir {
    ($dir,$tmpfile_ref) = @_;
    opendir(CURRENT, $dir);
    @files = readdir(CURRENT);
    closedir(CURRENT);

    foreach $file (@files) {
        if( $file eq ".." || $file eq "." ) { next; }
        if( -d $dir."/".$file ) { rec_dir($dir."/".$file,$tmpfile_ref); }
        elsif( $file =~ /^tmp/ && $file =~ /\.txf$/ ) { push(@{$tmpfile_ref},$dir."/".$file); }
    }
 }

 @matching_files = ();
 $start_dir = ".";
 rec_dir($start_dir,\@matching_files);
 foreach $file (@matching_files) { print($file."\n"); }
```

I didn't test it.  Barring typographical errors I think it will work.